# Pyqt5 inheritance

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

full code: [link to file](http://www47.zippyshare.com/v/zQJU7AqR/file.html)

I'm trying to build a GUI using PyQT5, and I have two classes:

In the main class "Window", I have a method to close/exit the GUI, and when I use the method within the class, everything is working

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
   choice = QMessageBox.question(self, '     WARNING!!!!', 'Are you sure to {}'.format(message),
                                  QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No,
                                  QMessageBox.No)
   if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
        print('Quiting Application')
        return sys.exit()
   else:
        pass
```

But the problem starts here, with the second class, when I try to quit using other class : **Q_button.clicked.connect(Window.close_app)**

```
class NewGrid(QWidget):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super(NewGrid, self).__init__(parent)

      grid = QGridLayout()
      grid.addWidget(self.createExampleGroup(), 0, 0)
      grid.addWidget(self.check_box_vBBU(), 21, 21)
      grid.addWidget(self.button_test(), 0, 1)
      grid.addWidget(self.quit_button(), 2, 2)

      self.setLayout(grid)

    def quit_button(self):
      groupBox = QGroupBox("Quit_placeholder")
      Q_button = QPushButton('Quit', self)
      box = QHBoxLayout()
      box.addWidget(Q_button)
      super()

      **Q_button.clicked.connect(Window.close_app)**
      groupBox.setLayout(box)
      return groupBox
```

any solution?

edit: 
Here is the full code

```
import sys
from ctypes import windll
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

SCREEN_WIDTH = windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0)  # 1920
SCREEN_HEIGHT = windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)  # 1080


class CustomDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDialog, self).__init__(parent=None)
        Qbtn = QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel
        self.buttonBox.accepted(self.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected(self.reject)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(SCREEN_WIDTH / 3, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 3, SCREEN_WIDTH / 3,
                         SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2)  # (start_point_X,start_point_Y,DIMensionX,DimensionY)

        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('dru_icon.png'))
        self.setWindowTitle('----------------------DRU GUI-----------------')
        self.statusBar()
        self.file_menu()
        self.view_menu()
        self.toolbar_menu()
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        # btn = QPushButton('quit', self)
        # btn.clicked.connect(self.close_app)
        # make the buttons near the bottom right: 1920-50=450, 1080-50=250
        # btn.move(450, 250)
        # btn.resize(50, 50)
        # btn.move(SCREEN_WIDTH / 3 - 50, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - 50)

        label = QLabel("Holla")
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.setCentralWidget(label)
        widget = NewGrid()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.show()

    def toolbar_menu(self):
        toolbar = QToolBar("My Main Toolbar")
        toolbar.setIconSize(QSize(32, 32))  # manual size
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)  # showing toolbar

        icon1 = self.set_toolbar_icon('new_icon', icon_image='truck--plus')
        icon1.triggered.connect(self.close_app)
        icon2 = self.set_toolbar_icon('iconNum2')
        # icon2.triggered.connect(self.notification_button)
        icon3 = self.set_toolbar_icon('iconNum3', icon_image='application-monitor')

    def set_toolbar_icon(self, icon_name="NONE", icon_image='animal-monkey.png', Width=32, Length=32):
        toolbar = QToolBar("My Main Toolbar")
        toolbar.setIconSize(QSize(Width, Length))  # manual size
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)  # showing toolbar
        icon_name = QAction(QIcon(icon_image), icon_name, self)
        # icon_name.triggered.connect(
        #     self.notification_button)  # add different command later, for now its quitting,
        self.toolBar = self.addToolBar('RUN IT')
        # self.toolBar.addAction(icon1) #will be the default icon size from windows
        toolbar.addAction(icon_name)
        return icon_name

    # ------main menu dialog --------
    def file_menu(self):
        # creating a toolbar with menu
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('File')
        quit_tooltip = QAction('&Quit', self)
        quit_tooltip.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        quit_tooltip.setToolTip('close the app')
        # quit_tooltip.triggered.connect(self.close_app)
        quit_tooltip.triggered.connect(self.close_app)
        fileMenu.addAction(quit_tooltip)

    def view_menu(self):
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        viewMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('View')

    # ------main menu dialog --------
    def notification_button(self):
        return self.areYouSure_toolbar(message='NO ACTION DEFINED')

    def close_app(self):  # defined our own method of closing
        # choice = QMessageBox.question(self, '     WARNING!!!!', 'Are you sure to quit?',
        #                               QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No,
        #                               QMessageBox.No)  # the last  QMessageBox.No is to highliht the option implicitly
        choice = self.areYouSure_toolbar(message='Quit')
        if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
            print('Quiting Application')
            return sys.exit()
        else:
            pass

    def areYouSure_toolbar(self, message='____'):
        choice = QMessageBox.question(self, '     WARNING!!!!', 'Are you sure to {}'.format(message),
                                      QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No,
                                      QMessageBox.No)  # the last  QMessageBox.No is to highliht the option implicitly
        return choice


class NewGrid(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(NewGrid, self).__init__(parent)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.createExampleGroup(), 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.check_box_vBBU(), 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.button_test(), 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.check_box_LPR(), 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.quit_button(), 3, 3)
        # grid.addWidget(self.createExampleGroup(), 1, 2)
        self.setLayout(grid)

        # temp = Window()

        # self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Group Box")
        # self.resize(400, 300)

    def check_box_vBBU(self):
        groupBox = QGroupBox("Input (From vBBU) ")

        checkbox1 = QCheckBox('Port {}'.format(1), self)
        checkbox2 = QCheckBox('Port {}'.format(2), self)

        check_box = QHBoxLayout()
        check_box.addWidget(checkbox1)
        check_box.addWidget(checkbox2)

        check_box.addStretch(1)
        groupBox.setLayout(check_box)
        return groupBox

    def check_box_LPR(self):
        groupBox = QGroupBox("Output (from LPR) ")

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        for n in range(20):
            btn = QCheckBox('LPR' + str(n))
            # btn.pressed.connect(self.close_app_Newgrid) #where to connect
            layout.addWidget(btn)
            # btn.setChecked(True)

        num_of_buttons = n
        # widget = QWidget()

        selectRandom_btn = QPushButton('Random ports')
        layout.addWidget(selectRandom_btn)
        selectAll_btn = QPushButton('All')
        selectAll_btn.pressed.connect(lambda : self.select_buttons(num_of_buttons, btn))
        layout.addWidget(selectAll_btn)
        groupBox.setLayout(layout)
        return groupBox

    def select_buttons(self, num_of_buttons,btn):
        for x in range(1,num_of_buttons-1):
           btn.setC
        # btn[1].setChecked(True)

    def quit_button(self):

        groupBox = QGroupBox("Quit_placeholder")
        Q_button = QPushButton('Quit', self)
        box = QHBoxLayout()
        box.addWidget(Q_button)
        super()
        # Q_button.clicked.connect(self.close_app_Newgrid)
        # Q_button.clicked.connect(Window.close_app)
        groupBox.setLayout(box)
        return groupBox

    def button_test(self):
        groupBox = QGroupBox("test buttons")

        btn1 = QPushButton("Push me", self)
        # btn1.clicked.connect(self.close_app)# need to connect the button somewhere..

        vbox = QHBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(btn1)
        # vbox.addStretch(1)
        groupBox.setLayout(vbox)
        return groupBox

    def createExampleGroup(self):
        groupBox = QGroupBox("Data type")

        radio1 = QRadioButton("Binary")
        radio2 = QRadioButton("Decimal")

        radio1.setChecked(True)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(radio1)
        vbox.addWidget(radio2)

        vbox.addStretch(1)
        groupBox.setLayout(vbox)

        return groupBox

    def close_app_Newgrid(self):  # defined our own method of closing
        choice = QMessageBox.question(self, '     WARNING!!!!', 'Are you sure to quit?',
                                      QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No,
                                      QMessageBox.No)  # the last  QMessageBox.No is to highliht the option implicitly

        if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
            # print('Quiting Application')
            return sys.exit()
        else:
            return


def run():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    Gui = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


run()
```

update :

I tried to simplify the solution below:

```
        for w in QApplication.topLevelWidgets():
            if isinstance(w,Window):
               w = True
        windows = w
```

Comment: provide a [mcve], how do you create a Window and NewGrid object?

Comment: i'm editing this right now, with the complete code..

Comment: Use [window()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#window): `Q_button.clicked.connect(self.window().close_app)`.

Comment: copied that line.. it doesnt run..

Comment: @DannyKaminski that code is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection is between the signal of one object and the slot of another, not between classes, so the instruction is incorrect.

So in order to perform this task we must get some way to the Window object, a possible solution is to take advantage of Window is the window, so it is a top-Level for it we use the `topLevelWidgets()` method and we filter through `isinstance()`:

```
def quit_button(self):

    groupBox = QGroupBox("Quit_placeholder")
    Q_button = QPushButton('Quit', self)
    box = QHBoxLayout()
    box.addWidget(Q_button)
    #Q_button.clicked.connect(self.close_app_Newgrid)
    windows = [w for w in QApplication.topLevelWidgets() if isinstance(w, Window)]
    if windows:
        Q_button.clicked.connect(windows[0].close_app)
    groupBox.setLayout(box)
    return groupBox
```

***Note:*** the problem is not due to inheritance.

Comment: excellent, it did solve it.
1) maybe you have some sort of reference to it? - i just want to understand it better the line you wrote..
2) so, basically, if i have a method i want to use for different class, i can use this 'topLevelWidgets'?

Comment: @DannyKaminski topLevelsWidgets() returns the widgets that are windows, and can be used on either side of the widgets. I do not understand what you mean by reference, maybe http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#topLevelWidgets. If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the [tour], that's the best way to thank

Comment: hi, thanks again. what i meant is some examples, the site is giving me documentation in CPP..
i tried to 'break' it to simpler code, if it is not a hassle, can you just make it more implicit for me? or just reference to python examples?.. thanks

Comment: @DannyKaminski 
In the documentation the important thing is not as it is the nomenclature of the function, but the explanation of the functions, methods, classes, etc. Most of the PyQt5 documentation points to the Qt5 documentation, so you must learn to understand it. On the other hand if you want to see examples, download the source code of PyQt5, and there you will find many examples: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.10.1/PyQt5_gpl-5.10.1.zip